# javascript calculation not working keeps returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html, nan

Need help using the alert dialogue box to return the value from the calculation for the the whole sale cost and retail markup variables. It shows up as NaN.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>

            </head>
            <body>
                <button onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>
                <p id="demo"></p>

                <script>
                    // Create an application that lets the user enter an item’s 
                       wholesale cost and its markup percentage.
                        function myFunction() {
                        var wholeSaleCost;
                        var markUpPercentage;
                        var retailPrice;

                        wholeSaleCanDollars = prompt("Please enter the wholesale cost of the item:");
                        markupCostCanDollars = prompt("Please enter the markup cost for the same item:");

                        retailPrice = calculateRetail(wholeSaleCost, markUpPercentage);
                        alert(retailPrice);
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
                    }

                    function calculateRetail(wholeSale, markUp) {
                        var markUpConverted = markUp / 100;
                        var markUpAmount = (wholeSale * markUpConverted);
                        var retail = (wholeSale + markUpAmount);
                        return retail;
                    }`enter code here`

                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: `wholeSaleCost` is undefined!

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, there is no need to convert your inputs to numbers, because divide etc. operations automatically convert them to numbers (still, as a good practice and for consistency you should always convert your string inputs to numbers).

The error is that you have stored inputs in some variables, and passed on some other variables (which are `undefined`) to your function. Correct this and your code works fine:

```js
                    // Create an application that lets the user enter an item’s                        wholesale cost and its markup percentage.
                        function myFunction() {
                        var wholeSaleCost;
                        var markUpPercentage;
                        var retailPrice;

                        wholeSaleCost = prompt("Please enter the wholesale cost of the item:");
                        markUpPercentage = prompt("Please enter the markup cost for the same item:");

                        retailPrice = calculateRetail(wholeSaleCost, markUpPercentage);
                        alert(retailPrice);
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
                    }

                    function calculateRetail(wholeSale, markUp) {
                        var markUpConverted = markUp / 100;
                        var markUpAmount = (wholeSale * markUpConverted);
                        var retail = (wholeSale + markUpAmount);
                        return retail;
                    }
```

```html
                <button onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>
                <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your cost input to number using `parseInt or parseFloat`. Update your script with following.

```
 retailPrice = calculateRetail(parseInt(wholeSaleCost), parseInt(markUpPercentage));
```

Comment: `parseInt()` or  `parseFloat()`

Comment: this wont fix the problem ... `parseFloat(undefined)` is `NaN` - the two vars passed to the function are `undefined` :p